# Stack Overflow Javascript issues?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, javascript

For some reason I can't seem to post comments right now, and code styling isn't working.

`http://sstatic.net/so/js/master.js?v=4360` is giving a 206 partial content, and trying to open it directly in FF is giving me the following error message:

> Content Encoding Error
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot
>   be shown because it uses an invalid or
>   unsupported form of compression.
>
> ```
> *   Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to reproduce it again either, but I'm pretty sure it had something to do with cache corruption in firefox and nothing to do with your site.  It was bugging me and I eventually cleared the cache, the problem went away.

Sorry for forgetting to update the post on meta, or the absolute failure of me to post the headers of my request to help you try and find the problem.  I would be a horrible bug-tester ;)

Cheers.