# Cannot load javascript file on stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, stack-overflow, javascript

I can't use a lot of stackoverflows features because I fail to load one of your javascript files.

The file in question is:

`http://sstatic.net/so/js/question.js?v=5935`

and I get this error:

```
Content Encoding Error

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.
```

Tells me to contact the website administrator so here ya go. :)

Comment: What browser/OS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Problems like this have been reported before ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22778/ask-your-question-button-is-disabled), [and here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21629/stack-overflow-javascript-issues)) but get tagged no-repro since it seems to be a client side problem.

Just clear your cache and it should fix the issue.